# Error while connecting to Active directory domain controller "An active directory domain controller could not be contacted"

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, active-directory

I have two EC2 servers on the private network (they have the same Private subnet) on AWS and the first server is both AD DC and a DNS.
DNS server info:

[image: DNS info]

I have set the IP address of server 1 as DNS in server 2.

[image: TCP]

Now when I ping the IP address of the DNS server from server 2 it's successful.
[image: Ping]

I can ping the Computer name (dns.xyxyx.local) too;

[image: Ping]

Pinging just the domain name works as well:

[image: Ping]

But can't ping the just host name (dns);

[image: Ping]

And while trying to join the domain controller I get the following error:

[image: Error]

Can anyone tell me why it can't join the AD DC? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that AWS Security Group was blocking this. For now (Just test) I allowed all traffic and it's fixed.